# PWM SPI I2C GPIO on android for Orange pi pc

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, wiringpi, orange-pi

I want to connect an RF24 Transceiver to my Orange pi Pc board
that installed Official android on it

I can turn on and turn off some digital pins  with ADB command and set value to "/sys/class/gpio" Address in Android Os
but I want to use Spi communication for RF24 module
I try to use WiringOP library (Edited version of WiringPi) for this purpose
and compile and run my sample code with NDK Successfully

this is  my CPP code that calls from java MainActivity

```
wiringPiSetupSys();
pinMode (110, OUTPUT) ;
digitalWrite (110, 1) ;
```

number 110 refers to GPIO.1 base on this image

[pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msuks.jpg)

( is correct ?)
I cannot use wiringPiSetup() because cause Exception and error on android

what should I do? how can I use wiringOp on android os?